# Is String.length() invoked for a final String?

Tags: java, string, final

A quickie just to get peace of mind:
Considering the following

```
final String str = "This is the end";
```

Is `str.length()` evaluated at runtime or is it hardcoded as 15 in the bytecode?

Comment: The `javac` compiler is unlikely to optimise it, the JIT however is very likely to to if you run the code enough to warm it up.

Comment: Why care? This is probably JVM-implementation-dependent, but it'll likely be fast under and JVM. If this turns out to be a performance bottleneck (unlikely) a profiler will show it.

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java. It doesn't matter if you make the variable `final` or not.

Comment: It *does* matter, although not in the scope of the question. A final variable can not be re-assigned, while a normal variable could.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`str.length()` *is* evaluated at runtime. `final` means that value of the reference cannot be changed. It has nothing to do with the string itself.

However, if you look into the source code of `String` you will see that `length()` returns the value of a field, so no computation takes place, the value os simply read...

Answer (score 13):

`str.length()` is calculated in `String constructor` and saved in `private final int count;`, `str.length()` just returns the `count` variable. I just checked the Source here http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html

Answer (score 2):

In the bytecode the method will be evaluated.

However, the method call will likely be inlined during [jit compilation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15058/underst_jit.htm)

The code for the String.length() method is as follows:

```
public int length() {
    return count;
}
```

I don't think the fact that the reference to the string is declared final has any bearing on the inlining in this case.

Comment: And that would mean...the value is evaluated @ runtime & then are coded by jit?